# how to take user input of length and breadth in this program

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, getter-setter

this is the program i wrote i just want to take the user input of  length  and breadth in this program what shod i do to take user input. i had tried this but have no idea now how to take input in getter and setter :

```java
public class Area{

    int a,c;  // length and breadth
    
    Area(int l, int b){
        a = l;
        c = b;
    }

    public int setDim(){
        int results = a * c;
        return results;
    }
    
    public void getArea(){
        System.out.println("Area = " +  setDim());
    }

    public static void main(String []args){
        Area x =new Area(6,5);
        x.getArea();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `Scanner` class for taking input from user. There are many articles online that can help you understand how to take input

Comment: but how in getters and setters?

Comment: You don't take input in getters and setters.  That's not their purpose.

Comment: Also a getter shouldn't print a value.  It's purpose is to **get** the value; i.e. return it.